# how to change the date control in day pilot scheduler using in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, daypilot-scheduler

Hi I'm new to day pilot scheduler,

I have referred this day pilot scheduler https://code.daypilot.org/54503/angularjs-timesheet-tutorial-javascript-php to use my time sheet.

here what I want is I want to select date depend upon sidebar calender.

Here I don't know how the current date is selected.

[image]

In timesheet I want to show only the selected week.

```
days: new DayPilot.Date().daysInMonth(),
startDate: new DayPilot.Date().firstDayOfMonth(),
```

I tried to understand the code but it is little bit difficult to me.

can any one tell me how to set the selected date depends upon side calender control.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.scheduler = { 
viewType: "Days", 
showNonBusiness: false, 
businessBeginsHour: 9, 
businessEndsHour: 17, 
cellWidthSpec: "Auto", 
scale: "CellDuration", 
cellDuration: "15", 
useEventBoxes: "Never", 
days: 7, 
startDate: (new DayPilot.Date().firstDayOfWeek())}
```

after using days:7

it return 7 days only

https://forums.daypilot.org/Topic.aspx/3974/daypilot-scheduler-end-date-set-as-current